# Fatal Error on enabling modules

Tags: 7

I have enabled couple of ubercart modules in a drupal 7 site. After enabling it , I am getting error

> Fatal error: Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0

I dont know how to debug this error. I have even tried putting a try/catch block in index.php file of drupal.
but still it doesn't produce any custom message by which I can track the error.

Has any of you guys reproduce the error and how you guys fixed it.

Any pointers on it would be really helpful.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/10746064 and http://www.drupal4hu.com/node/222

Comment: tks..indeed that helped a lot to debug the error.